# iOS event bound using addEventListener is not triggering

Tags: ios, safari, vuejs2

I'm trying to bind a click event to `document`. Click bound using addEventListener is not triggering. Click is only triggered when clicked on an element having `v-on:click` event.

This is happening in iOS.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1x9hg0L9/)

Please try clicking on the orange and grey areas in the fiddle on iOS Safari.

Please help!

Comment: I tried it in Safari and I'm pretty sure I'm getting the same response. Why are you adding 'document.addEventListener('click', this.documentClick)'?

Comment: @hdifen I'm trying to close my custom drop down component when the user touches outside of my component. Is there any Vue-way to bind listener to body from an component?